# Show that a linear map on a finite dimensional complex vector space always have an eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, alternative-proof

What is an alternative proof that a  linear map $T$ on a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ with dimension $n$ always has an eigenvalue?

Here is the original proof idea:

We take a no zero vector $v\in V$, then $\{v,T(v),...,T^n(v)\}$ is linearly dependent. 
So there exists $a_i$, not all zero such that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iT^i(v)=0$.

Pick $m$ smallest such that $a_m$ is not zero. $m\neq 0 $ because $v\neq 0$. Then the polynomial $a_0+a_1z+...+a_mz^m$ can be factored as linear terms $c(z-c_1)...(z-c_m)$. So then $c(T-c_1I)...(T-c_mI)(u)=0$ and so one of $(T-c_iI)$ is not surjetive for some $i$. And then $c_i$ would be an eigenvalue.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're looking for an alternate proof?  Is there a step that you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Yes is there a proof without using fundamental theorem of algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assertion that you are trying to prove is equivalente to the fundamental theorem of Algebra. To be more precise:

> **Proposition:** Given a field $k$, the following assertions are equivalent:

- > Every non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $k$ has a root in $k$.
- > For each $n\in\mathbb N$, every endomorphism $T$ of $k^n$ has an eigenvalue.

In fact, you already know that the first condition implies the second one. On the other hand, if the second condition holds, then let $P(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $k$. You want to prove that it has a root in $k$ and you can assume without loss of generality that it is a *monic* polynomial. But then $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of its [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Since this matrix has an eigenvalue, $P(x)$ has a root in $k$.

So, if you whish to avoid the fundamental theorem of Algebra, you will have to use something basically equivalent to it.

Comment: Historically, did people proved the fundamental theorem of algebra first then use that to prove this theorem or they proved this theorem first and then use this theorem to determine the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: They proved the fundamental theorem of Algebra first. By many years.

Comment: Very good answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

A short proof would be: consider T as an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ consider $f(\lambda)=\det(I\lambda-M)$ this is a polynomial of order $n\geq1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ hence by the fundamental theorem of algebra has a root, namely an eigenvalue.

The fundamental theorem of algebra is essential here as one needs the polynomial $f(\lambda)$ to have a root. Without this:

$M=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$ becomes a counterexample as it only has complex eigenvectors.

Comment: If you add the proof of the fact about determinants that you use here this becomes a much longer proof than the one the OP gave...